# setting precision of floating point numbers same while writing and reading in binary files

Tags: c++, iostream, floating-point-precision

I have a code that writes floating point numbers acquiring real time from a machine and copying to binary file.

```
WriteToFile(float* buffer, int bufSize )
{
   ofstream out;
   out.open(m_fileName, ios::app);

   if (out  )
   {
      cout<<" Writing file "<<endl;
      for(int i=0; i< bufSize; i++)
      {
         out.precision(6);
         out.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
         out.write( (const char*) &buffer[i], sizeof(float));

         cout << buffer[i] << ", ";
      }

      cout << endl;

      posp += bufSize;
      out.close();
   }
}
```

Here float* buffer is a pointer to an array that brings data from the machine and int bufSize is the size ( total numbers in the buffer to be written, say 70 numbers).

The data is later read as floating point numbers

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open(m_fileName);
if (fin ))
{
   fin.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
   fin.seekg(posg);
   fin.read((char*)buffer,bufSize*sizeof(float));
   posg = fin.tellg();
}
fin.close();
```

Code is working well, except the order of the numbers read is getting disordered in the middle of reading, i am assuming it has got some thing do with the precision set.i have set precision  6 for writing and no precision set for reading, Can any one help me synchronizing the precision for both writing and reading the binary files

Comment: `the order of the numbers read is getting disordered` This is unclear to me, could you elaborate ? Show a sample of the data you read ?

Comment: Why are you using `fin.seekg(posg);`? How do you make sure `posg` points to the right place in the file?

Comment: When you are using `out.write()` and `fin.read()`, the precision settings don't matter. You are just writing and reading bytes of data.